# Dynamic extends abstract class on angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm setting up an new angular app that support both web and app( using cordova). The question is how can I dynamic extends the abstract class that will suitable for both environment.

I have the environment config like.

**environment.app.ts**

```js
{
    url: 'https://localhost',
    isAppEnv: true
}
```

**environment.web.ts**

```js
{
    url: 'http://example.com',
    isAppEnv: false
}
```

This abstract will use for web

```js
export abstract class ProductOnWebService {
    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }
    abstract description();
    updateProductDetail(data): Observable<any> {
        const url = environment.url + '/products?productId=' + data.id;
        const params = JSON.stringify({params: data});
        return this.http.post(url, params).map(res => res);
    }
}
```

And this abstract will use for app

```js
export abstract class ProductOnWebService {
    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }
    abstract description();
    updateProductDetail(data): Observable<any> {
        const url = environment.url + '/products/' + data.id;
        const params = JSON.stringify(data);
        return this.http.post(url, params).map(res => res.data);
    }
}
```

How can i extends the abstract base on the environment?

**books.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class BookProductService extends ??? {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        super(http);
    }

    description() {
        return {name: '', description: '', prize: 1000};
    }
}
```

Comment: All of this because your API urls vary a little bit? Your abstract classes are exactly the same outside of the url. Why not just add the full url into the environment object, too?

Comment: @R.Richards I have think of it but some API not different a little. For example: On web i have call like `http://example.com/customer/customer001/orders/order001` but on app it just `http://localhost/orders/order001`. And you can see the body of post method and the return is unlike the other too.